# structures for multilevel feedback queue initialization

Tags: c, struct, queue, feedback, multi-level

Helllo,

I am trying to build a multilevel feedback queue and im having an issue with accessing the data structures.

```
struct str1
{
`    int time;
     int Id;
     int Size;
     struct str1 *next;
};

struct mlfq
{
     int quantum;
     int timereached;
     struct mystruct p;
};

struct str1 *front; //read from the file and stored.

struct mlfq *ml;
```

What I want to do is link the "mlfq" to the other "front" queue.

In my insert function, I have allocated memory

```
struct mlfq *ptr;  
    struct str1 *temp;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct mlgq)
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct str1));
        ptr->p = front;
```

getting error: INCOMPATIBLE TYPES IN ASSIGNMENT.
Now front is loaded and im trying to get the contents of queue structure "front" to link to it.

Can anyone tellme what;s going on?

Comment: Did you rename the "str1" struct to "mystruct" while posting?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
ptr->p = front;
```

`ptr->p` is of type `struct str1` or `struct mystruct` (you seem to be mixing them up), while `front` is of type `struct str1 *` or `struct mystruct *`. You're trying to assign a pointer to a variable of a non-pointer type. You need to dereference `front` for the assignment to be correct. A statement that compiles properly would be

```
ptr->p = *front;
```

Answer (score -1):

I once had implemented Multilevel feed back queue scheduling algorithm(which was a creation of my own).I had made 3 queues, first one with time quantum 10ms(FCFS),second one with time quantum 40ms(FCFS) and the third and the last one with just First come first serve Algo.